# How to find object on a column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I've a list that has a key that is a list of objects and i'm trying to filter the first result that matches my condition

The list;

```
contet = [{'name': 1, 'includes': [{'t': 3}, {'t': 2}]},
 {'name': 2, 'includes': [{'t': 1}, {'t': 6}]},
 {'name': 3, 'includes': [{'t': 2}, {'t': 4}]}]
```

I've manage to explode the list to make it more easier to find:

```
pandas.DataFrame(content).set_index('name').explode('includes')
```

The result is:

```
  includes
name          
1     {'t': 3}
1     {'t': 2}
2     {'t': 1}
2     {'t': 6}
3     {'t': 2}
3     {'t': 4}
```

How can i find the first occurrence (on includes) for `1` and `2` using the key `t`?

What i'm trying to avoid is a nested `for` and `ifs` like this:

```
result_one, result_tow, [], []
for name, item in frame:  # this will loop through all list
    if item['includes']['t'] == 1:
        result_one.append(item['includes']['t'])
    if item['includes']['t'] == 2:
        result_two.append(item['includes']['t'])

# this will get only the object in `includes`
one = result_one[0]
two = result_two[0]
```

The expected result is to get the first occurrence of `1` and `2` on `includes` list

one should be equal to:

```
{'name': 2, 'includes': [{'t': 1}, {'t': 6}]}
```

two should be equal to:

```
{'name': 1, 'includes': [{'t': 3}, {'t': 2}]}
```

Comment: What output are you expecting¿

Comment: @yatu i've added in the question

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming 'includes' column is a list of dicts**

```
df[df['includes'].apply(pd.Series)['t']==2]
```

Output will be:

```
        includes  name
1  {u't': 2}     1
4  {u't': 2}     3
```

Get first occurrence details:

```
df['id']=df.index #optional
df[df['includes'].apply(pd.Series)['t']==2].iloc[0]
```

Output:

```
includes    {u't': 2}
name                1
id                  1
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

If it is not a list of dicts (i.e. if you get key errors) then:

```
from ast import literal_eval 
df['includes']=df['includes'].apply(literal_eval)
df[df['includes'].apply(pd.Series)['t']==2].iloc[0]

name=df[df['includes'].apply(pd.Series)['t']==2].iloc[0]['name']
```

Thanks to yatu for pointing that I shouldn't be matching with string

**Assuming 'includes' column is a list of strings only**

```
df[df['includes']=="{'t':2}"]
df[df['includes']=="{'t':2}"].iloc[0]

name=df[df['includes']=="{'t':2}"].iloc[0]['name']
```

The above answer(s) are for getting first occurrence details ('name', index of df).

If you wish to get the list of all dicts in the given name (pertaining to first occurrence), then:

```
df[df['name']==name]
```

Shall give the list.

**Obtain it as original object format:**

```
[names for names in contet if names['name']==name]
```

Comment: Are you using a string instead of a dict there...?

Comment: TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Comment: Thanks @yatu, have corrected the answer for dict, Rafa Acioly does this work at your end?

Comment: I think OP wants more than one value, not just `1`

Comment: @JALO-JusAnotherLivngOrganism now i'm getting a `KeyError` for `t`

Comment: your examples will only retrieve the object inside the list `{'includes': [...]}`, not the complete object like the example on the question :(

Comment: Object format may be obtained by list comprehension as follows:
[names for names in contet if names['name']==name]

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension and numpy array slicing approach:

**Numpy array of your list of dicts:**

```
import numpy as np

contet = np.array([{'name': 1, 'includes': [{'t': 3}, {'t': 2}]},
{'name': 2, 'includes': [{'t': 1}, {'t': 6}]},
{'name': 3, 'includes': [{'t': 2}, {'t': 4}]}])
```

**List comprehension to find 't'==n ; 2 in the following case:**

```
boolean=np.where([True in [t['t']==2 for t in sublist['includes']] for sublist in contet])[0]
```

**Getting the subset:**

```
contet[boolean[0]]
```